Identify this flyback switching IC "01G262"
I am checking the circuit of a 12V 5A switching power supply. My problem is with the PWM controller IC. The code written on the IC is 01G262. Of course, I am not sure if the first letter is zero or the letter O. No matter how much I searched on the internet, I could not find the IC number and its datasheet from this marked code. IC package is SOT23-6.
someone told me it is RT8226. but I can't find any information about RT8226 too.


Shots of the circuit around it would be useful. How is it connected to other things?

Richtek usually has an = symbol (i.e. AB=CD) on their package markings I don't think it's an RT part. This could be a specialized part for an OEM. I can't find this anywhere

It's probably a Kiwi Instruments (必易微) KP201 AC-DC converter.


(Source: lcsc.com)
